# how to have one return statement in one method in java?

Tags: java, methods

I know how to have one return in a method in some easy situation, but when a method return an object from another class, I don't know how to give a variable to store the return value. The specific code showed below:

```
public Path findPath(Maze maze) {
    Path path = new Path();
    MazePosition initialPos = new MazePosition(0, 0, null);
    Stack<MazePosition> posForExplore = new Stack<MazePosition>();
    MazePosition pos = initialPos;
    MazePosition next;

    posForExplore.push(pos);
    while (!posForExplore.empty()) {
        pos = posForExplore.pop();
        switch (maze.getPosStatus(pos)) {
        case GOAL:
            MazePosition p = pos;
            while (p!=null) {
                path.insertFirst(p.getCoords()[0], p.getCoords()[1]);
                p =p.getFrom();
            }
            return path;
        case VISITED:
            break;
        case OBSTACLE:
            break;
        case OPEN:
            maze.setPosStatus(pos, MazeStatus.VISITED);
            for (Movement mov: DIRS_TO_EXPLORE) {
                next = maze.getNeighbour(pos, mov);
                if (next!=null&&(maze.getPosStatus(next)==MazeStatus.OPEN||maze.getPosStatus(next)==MazeStatus.GOAL)) {
                    posForExplore.push(next);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have a return path and return null, so how can I only have one return statement. Thank you so much!

Comment: it's unclear what you're wanting. please elaborate...

Comment: Please tell us a bit more. What should the method return under what conditions?

Comment: It is possible but quite awkward to rewrite that so there is only one return statement. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It is okay to have multiple return statements in a method. So are you asking in terms of "good coding practice" such that you want to improve your way of writing or are you asking a question because your code is not working? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Just return 'path' at the end.

Comment: An early return is similar to breaking out of a loop. Replacing an early return with a local variable and a labelled break makes readability worse.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. yes, my code can work, but want to have a "good coding practice".

Answer (score 2):

Declare and initialize `path` to `null`. Check for `null` before you insert anything and initialize it then (breaking the loop to trigger the return). At the end `return path`. Like,

```
public Path findPath(Maze maze) {
    Path path = null;
    MazePosition initialPos = new MazePosition(0, 0, null);
    Stack<MazePosition> posForExplore = new Stack<MazePosition>();
    MazePosition pos = initialPos;
    MazePosition next;

    posForExplore.push(pos);
    loop: while (!posForExplore.empty()) {
        pos = posForExplore.pop();
        switch (maze.getPosStatus(pos)) {
        case GOAL:
            MazePosition p = pos;
            while (p != null) {
                if (path == null) {
                    path = new Path();
                }
                path.insertFirst(p.getCoords()[0], p.getCoords()[1]);
                p = p.getFrom();
            }
            break loop;
        case VISITED:
            break;
        case OBSTACLE:
            break;
        case OPEN:
            maze.setPosStatus(pos, MazeStatus.VISITED);
            for (Movement mov : DIRS_TO_EXPLORE) {
                next = maze.getNeighbour(pos, mov);
                if (next != null && (maze.getPosStatus(next) == MazeStatus.OPEN
                        || maze.getPosStatus(next) == MazeStatus.GOAL)) {
                    posForExplore.push(next);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: But the result is different when I change the code. my result looks like this: /Users/simstudent/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-03-31 at 8.01.34 PM.png.     but after change the code, it looks like this:/Users/simstudent/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-03-31 at 8.02.37 PM.png.  I use the depth-first search, but have the preference search direction. but after change the code, it's different.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you must take

- Try to initialize new `Path` instance to null at the beginning of
  your method e.g. `pathReturn`
- In each `switch` statement, before doing `break`, assign `pathReturn`
  to your result and then `break`
- At the end of your method, just return `pathReturn` instead of `null`

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate `return path;` from the middle of the method, and only have a single `return` statement at the end, you need to be able to exit the loop from where the `return path;` is, and you need to specify that return value should not be `null`.

```
Path returnPath = null;
LOOP: while (!posForExplore.empty()) {
    ...
    switch (maze.getPosStatus(pos)) {
        case GOAL:
            ...
            returnPath = path;
            break LOOP;
        ...
    }
}
return returnPath;
```